# Angular 4: how to set a default radio button from a list

Tags: angular

I have a list of 4 items of which one should be selected.

In my component I have:

```
items = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4'];
currentItem = 'item3';
```

The submit of the form is:

```
onSubmit( form : NgForm ) {
    console.log( 'Before formaction current item = ' + this.currentItem);
    this.currentItem = form.value.item;
    console.log( 'After formaction current item = ' + this.currentItem);
}
```

My template is:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="radio" *ngFor="let item of items">
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="item" ngModel [value]="item" [checked]="item === currentItem"> {{ item }}
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I set a default? 
And of course get the value back?

Comment: Have you tried using '==' instead of '==='?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you dn't need `[checked]` try with `[(ngModel)]`

```
<input type="radio" name="item"  [value]="item" [(ngModel)]="currentItem" >
```

Comment: Great, this solves the question very elegantly. But why does it work?

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this ?

```
<input type="radio" name="item" ngModel [value]="item" 
   [checked]="item === currentItem || (currentItem === undefined 
       && item === defaultItem"> {{ item }}
</input>
```